# Why are non-standard file extension used for PHP files?

Tags: coding-standards

Is there any reason why Drupal decided to use non-standard file extensions, for example node.install, node.module, simple.profile, case.test? Why doesn't Drupal use .php as extension for PHP files?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's easier for the core to know about special files that way.

As a developer you're free to name your module or theme whatever you like, so that means that Drupal core needs another way to find and identify certain important files.  Doing this using the file extension is an easy way.

Comment: I think .module.php is not harder to find than .module

Comment: @AndyTruong you're right, but what's the point of adding the .php?  I can't see a reason where it would be helpful to have.

Comment: with .php, developers do not need configure their IDE. Code highlighting in code browser no more mess https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.0.x/core/modules/node/node.module